# Can't use Hibernate java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver

Tags: java, hibernate

I try to launch simple login application on GlassFish server. I use JSF and Hibernate. But there are some issues. Could anyone help me?

Here is stack trace:

```
    INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.1.Final}
    INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
    INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
    SEVERE: Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver
    WARNING: /index.xhtml @15,68 listener="#{loginBean.addPerson}":java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    javax.el.ELException: /index.xhtml @15,68 listener="#{loginBean.addPerson}": java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxHandler.java:450)
    at javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent.processListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent.java:113)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:760)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sadik.bookhouse.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:24)
    at com.sadik.bookhouse.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:8)
    at com.sadik.bookhouse.dao.PersonDaoImpl.addPerson(PersonDaoImpl.java:20)
    at com.sadik.bookhouse.view.LoginBean.addPerson(LoginBean.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    ... 35 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:927)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1476)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.reset(Configuration.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.reset(AnnotationConfiguration.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.<init>(AnnotationConfiguration.java:168)
    at com.sadik.bookhouse.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:12)
    ... 45 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.util.DTDEntityResolver
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1509)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1359)
    ... 57 more
```

HibernateUtil class:

```
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

    public class HibernateUtil {

        private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

        private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }

}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
      <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/book_house</property>   
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <mapping class="com.sadik.bookhouse.logic.Person" />
      </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

After debugging I found that exception throws in 
        return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

Comment: This problem is not directly related nor to JSF nor GlassFish. Please read the StackTrace in order to understand what the real problem is. This is the main line: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/util/DTDEntityResolver` looks like you're missing a library in *WEB-INF/lib* folder.

Comment: Lateral suggestion: I strongly recommend learning and using Maven or some other dependency resolver + packaging tool that takes care of this for you.

Comment: jta-1.1.jar was missing in WEB_INF/lib  folder. Thank you very mauch. It start work now. Sure I used maven to resolve this dependency.